# INSERT ... SELECT on a huge MySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have isolated MySQL 5.5 with a huge table inside ( 3.5TB of data and yes, it is only 1 table ).

The goal is to copy a half of this table into another one on the same server. How to do that better and quicker? :

1) Just `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE ...`. 
What will be MySQL behavior in this case? I expect that connection to MySQL will be broken by time out, however the query itself should run until all data are copied.
Or the MySQL will be just crashed with such query?

2) Using the same `INSERT ... SELECT` but selecting by chunks ( for example by 10000 rows). This should be definitely safer but much slower I guess.

What is the best way? Thank you in advance!

P.S. Before the insertion I will drop `FK` and indexes on new table + disable sql_log_bin and

Comment: Have you ever tried with tools such as Navicat. I'm using this tools for Data Transfer between database and servers without any problems, as long as we have reliable connection. But there were no options to select or cut into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Your option 2 will be the way to go, smaller chunks. Depending on the size of your rows, You could increase the rows to around 1M.

Comment: More discussion of [_chunking_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen ALTER TABLEs running for days. The problem is not a timeout, the problem is that if the query fails at some point, you'll have to restart it from scratch.

But what is your use case exactly? The server will continue to accept queries from the applications? If not, your idea is ok, I see no caveats.

Otherwise, use `pt-archive`. It is designed for this purpose, and it avoids to overload a server.

However: **don't disable the binlog!** You will break incremental backups for no reason! Just run `SET binlog_format = 'STATEMENT'`.

Instead, if the server doesn't need to accepts connections from applications, and the table is InnoDB, you can restart it with `--innodb-doublewrite=0`. The operation will be much faster. But then remember (it's vital) to restart it again, without that option.